# Can not download dependencies from maven

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

A month ago, I can build my Java Application successfully on my IntelliJ IDEA from scratch, and now, I have to upgrade my spring-boot to get some new features. But, after I change the version of spring-boot from 2.2.2.RELEASE to other version and click the button of Reload All Maven Projects, I get the message:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.3.pom
```

It was fine a month ago for downloading 2.2.2.RELEASE.
Why does the update fail at this time?
My information is as follows：
MacOS 12.2,Bundled (Maven 3), Java of 1.8, IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 ultimate.

my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.*</groupId>
    <artifactId>web-site</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <modules>
        <module>study-info</module>
        <module>cloud-api</module>
    </modules>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <mysql-connector-version>8.0.16</mysql-connector-version>
        <lombok-version>1.18.10</lombok-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>


<!--            <dependency>-->
<!--                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--            </dependency>-->



            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
            </dependency>



   
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>${mysql-connector-version}</version>
            </dependency>


  
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>${lombok-version}</version>
            </dependency>




        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>



</project>
```

Comment: The spring boot parent: `spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:6.2.3` does not exist in this version. The most recent version https://search.maven.org/search?q=a:spring-boot-starter-parent is 2.6.3

Comment: @khmarbaise Sorry,I write it wrongly,and I have updated my description.But, I still have the same problem.

Comment: First use `mvn clean package -U` and afterwards check https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: @khmarbaise I have tried that. But I get the error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.keziqu:web-site:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.6.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.3.pom and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 16, column 13: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org: nodename nor servname provided, or not known -> [Help 2]

Comment: That looks like a network error ...

Comment: What happens if you run `wget https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.6.3/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.6.3.pom` on the same machine you are running maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a network error.
I changed another network of my phone's hotspot and it worked.